# how to change date and 24 hour format to time points, starting at zero in google sheets or R

Tags: r, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is a google sheets question:

I have the following timestamp in my spreadsheet:

```
2021-03-26 22:02:56
2021-03-26 21:02:09
2021-03-26 20:02:53
2021-03-26 19:02:04
2021-03-26 18:02:47
2021-03-26 17:01:56
2021-03-26 16:02:37
2021-03-26 15:01:47
2021-03-26 14:02:28
2021-03-26 13:01:38
2021-03-26 12:02:20
2021-03-26 11:03:01
2021-03-26 10:02:12
2021-03-26 09:02:53
2021-03-26 08:02:04
2021-03-26 07:02:44
2021-03-26 06:01:55
2021-03-26 05:02:36
2021-03-26 04:01:46
2021-03-26 03:02:28
2021-03-26 01:01:39
2021-03-26 00:03:52
```

Now, it has a row per hour.
I want to convert it into time points of 24 time points where the beginning of the data starts at 0. this way:

```
0.04
0.08
0.13
0.17
0.21
0.25
0.29
0.33
0.38
0.42
0.46
0.50
0.54
0.58
0.63
0.67
0.71
0.75
0.79
0.83
0.88
0.92
0.96
1.00
```

Where #1 represents day 1, # 2 represents day 2 and so on. Each time stamp like this can take whole months, and I want to convert it easily.
BTW- I don't care to do it via R, but I have no clue how to do it, and it sounds to me that in one function in google sheets I might solve it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your original timestamps as posted are in reverse order to the output you show; and your output does not include the rounded `0.00` for timestamp `2021-03-26 00:03:52`, nor is there an entry that would equate to 1 (which would be `2021-03-27 00:00:00` or thereabout). So I'm a bit confused.

But assuming that you've simply made errors in the post, I'll offer a solution.

Supposing that your timestamps are in the range A2:A, you could place the following formula in B2 of an otherwise empty B2:B ...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A-DATEVALUE("3-26-2021")))`

Be sure to set the format for Column B to show only two decimal places: **Format > Number > Number**. Just keep in mind that the extended decimal point values will still be there "behind the scenes."

Comment: thank you, I actually did missed the 0/00 by accident. In addition, I copied the date and the time from different places, just to illustrate the idea. I don't have data that could adequate to 1. This data coming from hubs and it is not precise. i.e. my first documentation from this data is: 2021-05-31 02:12:59- so I need it to be categorised as 0.00, and then the next one as 0.04 and the next as 0.08 and so forth.  I will try what you have suggested and let you know. Should what you suggested work given the clarification?

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly. Btw, I saw that it does not matter whether or not I attach to the data the exact time within the raw, it works the same (: